# Iterate over list using for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

code:

```
d = ["my", "name", "is", "abc"]
a  = {x: x*2 for x in d}
print a
```

output:

```
{'is': 'isis', 'abc': 'abcabc', 'my': 'mymy', 'name': 'namename'}
```

the output was not in the order of "d" list.

I also tried this:

```
a = collections.Ordered({x: x*2 for x in d})
```

but couldn't got expected result.

How can i generate a dictionary with elements ordered same as "d" list ?

Comment: A dictionary has no order.

Comment: Does `a  = [(x, x*2) for x in d]` could do the job? As Tichodroma said, a dict doesn't have an order (except orderdedDict).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
OrderedDict([(x, x*2) for x in d])
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('my', 'mymy'), ('name', 'namename'), ('is', 'isis'), ('abc', 'abcabc')])
```